# ActionScript 3 Sockets not working on the web? - works fine on my desktop

Tags: actionscript-3, network-programming

I have created AS3 APP that works with http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html

The application works fine on my desktop, but if i upload it on my webserver, the flash sockets does not work, it connects but i'm unable to send or receive data.

How can i fix this?

Comment: +1 because I'm not sure why it has a -1 to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a security error to me, the server you are connecting to needs to return a socket policy file, read more about that here:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html